# AVAudioPlayer Stop Sounds iPhone SDK Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios4, avaudioplayer

hope you can help me (tried lots of things here, but nothing worked)

i want to play several sounds by pressing a button and i want one button to cancel the playing sounds.

header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface MainView : UIView <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>  {

    IBOutlet UILabel *SoundDescriptionLabel;
    IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *StopSoundButton;

}
- (IBAction)PlayFatGuyWalking:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)PlayRoadRunner:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)ShowInfoPopup:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)PlayChaosRunning:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)PlaySadTrombone:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)PlayBadJokeSound:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)PlayHorrorSynth:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)PlayLKWPeep:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)PlayUiToll:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)StopSound:(id)sender;



AVAudioPlayer *theAudio;



@end


//PlaySound Function
void playSound(NSString *filename,NSString *type){
    [theAudio stop];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:type];
    theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];


    [theAudio play];




}
```

.m file:
i want to call it like this

```
- (IBAction)StopSound:(id)sender {
    [theAudio stop];


}
```

why is the "theAudio" variable undeclared in the StopSound() function???

please help me :(

thx in advance

EDIT: IT WORKS NOW LIKE I DID IT ABOVE

THX!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because StopSound is not a method of a class, it's a C-style function. Why don't you just get rid of the C-style function and put the code directly into `- (IBAction)StopSound:(id)sender`?

Comment: like this? 
- (IBAction)StopSound:(id)sender {
 [theAudio stop];
 

}

Comment: If you want to be able to use theAudio, you have to store it somewhere, e.g. in an ivar of your class. Right now you're just putting it in a local variable inside the PlayAudio function, so it's inaccessible (and leaked) after that function returns.